# Should I sign an infographic?

Tags: print-design, designers, signage

I work in a company, but not as a graphic designer. I also studied graphic design, so they asked me to make an infographic on what to do in case of earthquakes. They will not pay me for it. My question is if I should sign my work, since I also do digital illustration and graphic design as a freelancer.

Comment: First make sure they also think you dont get paid! I mean do they expect you to do it on your work time with work equipment? If so they allmost certainly will think that they will own the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These can be really murky waters. The question is does this fall within the scope of your work at your company. This can be answered by looking at your employment contract - there's usually a statement regarding intellectual property rights. There's also the question of where you create the work - but even if you create it at home, it still may be the property of the employer based upon your employee contract.
My questions:

- Do you want to sign the work so you can claim ownership?
- Do you want to sign the work because you want to be paid additional?
- Did your employer ask you to do this since they know you have a side gig as a designer? What are *their* expectations as to ownership?

Depending on your relationship with your employer, I'd say approach them and negotiate for a separate contract for this type of design work. You actually may be able to turn them into a client. Just be sure there is a clear contract for this work along with estimates and invoices. I hate to say it but you might need the advice of an attorney with experience in intellectual property.

Lastly, if they don't want you to sign and see it as part of your scope of work, would they offer you permission to show the work as part of your portfolio.

This could end up being a great private resource for you if handled carefully.